# WinUI 3 Intercept Keyboard event

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, winui-3

I'm converting an app from UWP to the new WinUI 3. The most of things are the same except for keyboard events. I want to intercept keyboard events to create some shortcuts in my app. I'm having problem with CoreWindow property of MainWindow cause it's always null when I try to get it. Are there any other way to register keyboard events?

`Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown += CoreWindow_KeyDown;`

Comment: There's not any more a "current window" concept with WinUI3 since you can have multiple windows (where you only had one with UWP). For keyboard events you can register on a given control instance, for example on your Window instance's Current (UIElement) property.

Comment: I've already tried to use KeyDown Event of Page Control but I don't know why it doesn't work, the method associated with it's never called.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your comment, you need to use `KeyDown` event on a `Page`. This is the minimal sample code that works. Can you try this?

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Input;

namespace KeyboardEvents;

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        KeyDown += MainPage_KeyDown;
    }

    private void MainPage_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I’ve just tried and sometimes it works and sometimes not. If I have a textbox control in my page it doesn’t work at all cause the text box come first with the key down event. In UWP to solve this problem I have use the key down event of the entire window that come first of all but now I can’t get the current window

Comment: @Mate282 I had a similar issue with a Page that had TextBox controls and I had to add the this.ProcessKeyboardAccelerator event to the hosting page (ShellPage) and then I was able to capture all keyb presses.

Comment: @GuildOfCalamity could provide code snipped?

Answer (score 0):

As requested...

```
   public MainPage()
   {
       this.InitializeComponent();
       // Add a keyboard accelerator event:
       this.ProcessKeyboardAccelerators += MainPage_ProcessKeyboardAccelerators;

}

   void MainPage_ProcessKeyboardAccelerators(UIElement sender, ProcessKeyboardAcceleratorEventArgs args)
   {
       Debug.WriteLine($"[ProcessKeyboardAccelerators] {args.Modifiers} {args.Key}");
       if (args.Key == VirtualKey.B && (args.Modifiers == VirtualKeyModifiers.Menu || args.Modifiers == VirtualKeyModifiers.Control))
       {
           if (MainFrame.CanGoBack)
               MainFrame.GoBack();
           
           args.Handled = true;
       }
       else if (args.Key == VirtualKey.D && (args.Modifiers == VirtualKeyModifiers.Menu || args.Modifiers == VirtualKeyModifiers.Control))
       {
           if (!App.DebugMode)
               App.DebugMode = true;
           else
               App.DebugMode = false;

           args.Handled = true;
       }
   }
```